# How does Structured Streaming execute pandas_udf?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'd like to understand how structured streaming treats new data coming.

If more rows arrive at the same time, spark append them to the input streaming dataframe, right?

If I have a withColumn and apply a pandas_udf, the function is called once per each row, or only one time and the rows are passed to the pandas_udf?

Let's say something like this:

```
dfInt = spark \
    .readStream \
    .load() \
    .withColumn("prediction", predict( (F.struct([col(x) for x in (features)]))))
```

If more rows arrive at the same time, they are processed together or once per each?=
There is the chance to limit this to only one row per time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If more rows arrive at the same time, spark append them to the input streaming dataframe, right?

Let's talk Micro-Batch Execution Engine only, right? That's what you most likely use in streaming queries.

Structured Streaming queries the streaming sources in a streaming query using [Source.getBatch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala#L57) (DataSource API V1):

> **getBatch(start: Option[Offset], end: Offset): DataFrame**
>
> Returns the data that is between the offsets (`start`, `end`]. When `start` is `None`, then the batch should begin with the first record.

Whatever the source returns in a `DataFrame` is the data to be processed in a micro-batch.

> If I have a withColumn and apply a pandas_udf, the function is called once per each row

Always. That's how user-defined functions work in Spark SQL.

> or only one time and the rows are passed to the pandas_udf?

[This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs) says:

> Pandas UDFs are user defined functions that are executed by Spark using Arrow to transfer data and Pandas to work with the data.
>
> The Python function should take `pandas.Series` as inputs and return a `pandas.Series` of the same length. Internally, Spark will execute a Pandas UDF by splitting columns into batches and calling the function for each batch as a subset of the data, then concatenating the results together.
>
> If more rows arrive at the same time, they are processed together or once per each?

If "arrive" means "part of a single DataFrame", then "they are processed together", but one row at a time (per the UDF contract).

> There is the chance to limit this to only one row per time?

You don't have to. It's as such by design. One row at a time only.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I solved my problem, classifying all the row inside the pandas series in the pandas udf. May you tell me if we can use pandas_udf in scala? We are experiencing some performance and memory error using the pandas_udf. Thank you

Comment: @xcsob pandas_udf in scala? Not possible. And you don't need it actually. Pure UDFs should work just fine. Can you accept the answer if it worked fine for you? Thanks.

Comment: I need pandas_udf because I'm using a scikit model to classify streaming data. How could I achieve this using a pure udf?

Comment: Don't think it's possible, but I'd recommend asking a separate question. Thanks for accepting the answer!